# Invalid hook call when adding react-redux Provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm building a small app to learn how to use the Redux Toolkit (my knowledge of React/Redux is primarily from the Udacity course which is outdated).

The error message gives the top 3 reasons this error pops up, but it doesn't seem any of them apply to me.

1. Mismatching versions of React and React DOM? Both of mine are listed as dependencies and have the same version.
2. Breaking the rules of Hooks? Not using any hooks that I'm aware of. All my components are class components (Udacity, remember?). Furthermore, I've removed all the components from the App component's `render()` call, and the error persists.
3. More than one copy of React? `npm ls react` displays only one version.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here. Whenever I remove the Provider from the `ReactDOM.render()` call, the error goes away.

I've been staring at this for a while now, and I'm not getting anywhere. Posting what I think is the relevant code below.

I have one reducer currently:

**/src/features/mortgage/mortgageSlice.ts**

```ts
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface MortgageState {
  principal?: number
  rate?: number
  term?: number
  closingCosts?: number
  amortization?: { payment: number; schedule: Array<any> }
}

const payment = (rate: number, nper: number, pv: number) => {
  const pvif = Math.pow(1 + rate / 100, nper)
  return (rate / (pvif - 1)) * -(pv * pvif)
}

const computeSchedule = (
  principal: number,
  apr: number,
  nper: number,
  payment: number
) => {
  let schedule = []
  let remaining = principal
  for (let i = 0; i <= nper; i++) {
    // apr percent / 100 (to decimal) / 12 (months in a year)
    const interest = remaining * (apr / 100 / 12)
    const principal = payment - interest
    const row = [
      i,
      principal > 0 ? principal : 0,
      interest > 0 ? interest : 0,
      remaining > 0 ? remaining : 0,
    ]
    schedule.push(row)
    remaining -= principal
  }
  return schedule
}

const initialState: MortgageState = {}

const mortgageSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'mortgage',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateMortgageParams(state, action) {
      const { principal, rate, term, closingCosts } = action.payload
      state.principal = principal
      state.rate = rate
      state.term = term
      state.closingCosts = closingCosts
    },
    amortize(state, action) {
      const { principal, rate, term } = state
      if (principal && rate && term) {
        const pmt = payment(rate, term * 12, principal)
        const schedule = computeSchedule(principal, rate, term * 12, pmt)
        state.amortization = { payment: pmt, schedule }
      }
    },
  },
})

export const { updateMortgageParams, amortize } = mortgageSlice.actions

export default mortgageSlice.reducer
```

Root reducer:

**/src/app/rootReducer.ts**

```ts
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import mortgage from '../features/mortgage/mortgageSlice'

export default combineReducers({
    mortgage
})
```

Store:

**/src/app/store.ts**

```ts
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import rootReducer from './rootReducer'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
})

export default store
```

**/src/index.tsx**

```tsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './index.css'
import App from './app/App'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker'

import store from './app/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: There is no call to a hook anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: Welcome to my confusion. I’m not using hooks anywhere I know of.

Comment: Look for useSeletor in your code, you did not post any components so I don't know if you did or id not.

Comment: I don’t use useSelector, useState, nor useEffect anywhere.

Comment: Please reproduce the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq

Comment: What versions of react, react-redux, react-dom and redux-toolkit do you use

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri your question led me to the resolution. For some reason, react-redux and redux both showed up in my node_modules folder, and intellisense picked them up when importing them, but they weren't listed as dependencies in my package.json. How can that happen? I didn't manually edit my package.json file to remove them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it was annoyingly simple: I never ran `yarn add react-redux redux`

When importing react-redux and redux, VSCode intellisense recognized them. The packages were also found in my node_modules folder already. Both of these things led me to think the packages had already been added/installed.

Just running `yarn add react-redux redux` resolved the issue.

Comment: Great. I have a same issue, and "yarn add react-redux redux" not helps for me...

Comment: I had to `cd` one folder down then run the command again. Weird because everything seemed fine even if I was in the wrong directory...

Comment: Adding in this got me too, but I did not forget.  I did it in the server/api directory and not in the client directory.  Just incase anyone else did the install, check on the directory.

Answer (score 1):

For future users looking into this topic: I had the same problem but using node package management. I just had to install it using: `npm install react-redux` and `npm install redux`. Try it to the client subfolder if necessary.